# How to take from database names for Highcharts Pie Chart Slices

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts, highcharts

I just managed to make the Pie chart on Highcharts as i want to display the data.

Like this:

> data.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","psw");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("ftsosticket", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) FROM ost_ticket GROUP BY dept_id") or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    /*$row[1] = $r[1];*/
    array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

So for the display, i used this example index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test Pie Graphics</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Facility Explotacion Sistema'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: []
                }]
            }

            $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                options.series[0].data = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });



        });   
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So in the final display i just obtains Slice and % as result

I used this code to take the data from the database, in order to use as Slice names instead the $.getJSON default, but, didn't work.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php', 
            success: function(jsonData) {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                <snip>
                        series: [{
                          type: 'pie',
                          name: 'Content',
                          data: jsonData
                        }]
                <snip>
            },
            cache: false
        });
```

So, the question is, how to take the name directly from the database? i know that it's gonna be like (1,2,3,4, etc...) because that are the departments names, but, with that solved, i can override it to the real departments names.

Thanks in advance.

> Edit

I tested the Query and i discovered that only conts the tickets per id, w/o taking the respective dept_id, so i changed the sentence to:

```
"SELECT COUNT(ticket_id), dept_id FROM ost_ticket GROUP BY dept_id"
```

And now i have this from the query:
COUNT(ticket_id):1,2,2.
dept_id:18,2,11.

But i don't know how to take that dept_id onto the slices names.

Comment: How does your `jsonData` look like? Could you show an example?

Comment: I belive that it's gonna like:
X° (Where x it's the amounts of tickets of a dept_id), dept_id 1;
X° (Where x it's the amounts of tickets of a dept_id), dept_id 2;
and etc...

Comment: I edited the SQL Sentence, and now i obtain the count + dept_id, but i don't have managed to take that dept_id to the slices names.

Comment: You need to push name in the point object in you php code. The name can be extraced form sql query.

Comment: How i exacltly do that?

Comment: Use array like an example: array(name=>'name',y=>10,color=>'#ff0000') per point.